# Pandas compare values by dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, compare

I have a data like

```
Date, Name, Something
2020-04-01,John,10
2020-04-01,Ivory,5
2020-04-01,Sam,3
2020-04-02,John,5
2020-04-02,Ivory,2
2020-04-02,Sam,1
2020-04-02,John,20
2020-04-02,Ivory,3
2020-04-02,Sam,9
```

working with pandas, i want to compare yesterday value by name, with today result to get the increase, decrease. shift(3) won't work because number of names are different for each day.
How can i do it. I want to add previous number. I tried

```
df['old_data'] = df[(work['Name'] == df['Name']) & (df['Date'] ==
                                                                 (df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(days = 1))
                                                                 )]['Something']
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: `df.groupby('name')['Something'].diff()`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: 2020-04-02,Sam,9,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0:'2020-04-01', 1:'2020-04-01', 2:'2020-04-01', 
                             3:'2020-04-02', 4:'2020-04-02', 5:'2020-04-02', 
                             6:'2020-04-03', 7:'2020-04-03', 8:'2020-04-03'},
                    'Name': {0:'John', 1:'Ivory', 2:'Sam', 
                             3:'John', 4:'Ivory', 5:'Sam', 
                             6:'John', 7:'Ivory', 8:'Sam'},
                    'Something': {0:10, 1:5, 2:3, 
                                  3:5, 4:2, 5:1, 
                                  6:20, 7:3, 8:9}})

df['diff'] = df.groupby('Name')['Something'].diff()

df.dropna()
```

I changed your data by altering the last three dates to be '2020-04-03'.

Comment: One more question. In this case how can I get the max value for each Name

Comment: Replace diff() with max()

Comment: Doesn't work. It returns an object with max value for each user, not a value. So in table new row is always 0.

Comment: If you want to report the max value of Something for each Name, and add that as a column, so that the max will repeat for each row with that Name, do this: `df['max_Something'] = df.groupby(['Name'])['Something'].transform(max)`